# How to assign and display date value on date picker using sqlitedatareader object in C# using wpf

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, datepicker, wpf-controls

I want to reading a datetime value from a Sqlite database and assign it to datepicker control. Here is my code that i am trying:

```
try
            {
                sqlitecon.Open();

                string Query = "Select * from Customer_New where Cust_Id='" + val + "'  ";

                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlitecon);
              //  createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read()){
                if(!dr.IsDBNull(1))
                    date_open.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(1);
                if(!dr.IsDBNull(2))    
                    Date_Joining.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(2);
                if(!dr.IsDBNull(3))
                    txt_Title.Text = dr.GetString(3);
                if(!dr.IsDBNull(4))
                    txt_cardnum.Text =dr.GetString(4);

                }


                sqlitecon.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

The above code is executed on form load event .so when form loads it should load the date value from db table into date picker .but form is opening with Message box that shows exception "specified cast is not valid". Then it fails to load any value from db and if i remove date fields from assigning in while loop then rest of text fields are assigned correctly to form . My db foramt of date is :MM/DD/YYYY and is of type datetime . On debugging by putting break point at "date_open.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(1);" it shows system date and time .My db tables are following sequence: Cust_id | date_open | Date_Joining |..... .Please Help

Comment: If i test this command : DateTime temp = dr.GetDateTime(1); //it is throwing exception : "string was not recognize as a valid datatime" ..Is their is some problem with value stored in db?

Answer (score 0):

Diagnose error like this:
Specify column names in SELECT statement and pick them by using
`reader.GetOrdinal("DateColName")`
Code example:

```
if(!dr.IsDBNull(1))
  var d1 = dr.GetDateTime("DateColName1");
if(!dr.IsDBNull(2))
  var d2 = dr.GetDateTime("DateColName2");
date_open.DisplayDate = d1;
Date_Joining.DisplayDate = d2;
```

**UPDATE:**
Diagnosing...

```
string Query = "Select date_open from Customer_New where Cust_Id='" + val + "'  ";
/* your code */
while(dr.Read()){
    var dt_obj = dr[0];
    var bt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_obj);
}
```

Comment: So, conversion problem not in code types, but in db types. Now try query "SELECT date('now');" and read it in code. SQLLite datetime format should be "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"

Comment: alright ... then what to do now? conversion of date format in code or sqlite ...how ?please help

Comment: Did you succeed parsing "SELECT date('now');" ? I Updated answer. At what line you're getting error?

Comment: yes it successfully parsed in sqlite db it is giving result in this format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"

Comment: SQLiteDataReader reader = db.ExecuteSQL("Select date_open from Customer_New where Cust_Id='" + val + "'  "); how to define db??

Comment: SQLiteDataReader reader = createCommand.ExecuteSQL( .....  ExecuteSQL is not present and here i am using sqlite not sql ..any other execute function is not accepting any parameters of select command

Comment: Sorry for some mistakes, don't have environment for this. The problem is that dr.GetDateTime(1) expects this format only "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS", but your db has "MM/DD/YYYY" format. You should either change db format or parse reader's output like string or object and convert it to DateTime in code explicitly

Comment: ok if i change my db date to string then tell me command to convert string back to format that is MM/DD/YYYY that can be displayed on datepicker ..

Comment: var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("02/30/2015", "MM/DD/YYYY", null);

Comment: correction: DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("21/03/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);